# Converting a bubble chart from V3 to V4 in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, charts

I am new to D3 and I started converting a example bubble chart from v3 to v4. I am getting `bubble.nodes is not a function` similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368919/d3-bubble-chart-bubble-nodes-not-a-function).

However, I am not sure how to apply the filter. I have placed my code in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z2dSH1AGyAZ5wAZLXOOz?p=preview). Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `bubble(nodes)` is way different from `bubble.nodes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *layout* functionality in `d3` changed [substantially between versions 3 and 4](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#hierarchies-d3-hierarchy).  The gist of it is that you now need to call `d3.hiearchy` to [preprocess](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy) the data before passing it into the layout.  Reworking your code looks like this:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(json) {

  var root = d3.hierarchy(classes(json))
    .sum(function(d) { return d.value; });

  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(bubble(root).leaves())
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    ...
```

Updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1PairiqEt5KuX5vrzbgO?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help